# Error with inserting data into mysql via interface

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In inserting data into a database via an interface but I'm getting the error:

**Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in…filetext**

How do I fix this? and what does this mean, here is all my code for `THIS` section of worry:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['map'])){
    $map = $_GET['map'];
}

if (isset($_GET['task'])){
    $task = $_GET['task'];
}

include("../inc/header.php");
include("../inc/bookshelf.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    //display lb page 
    include("../inc/adminsidebar.html");?>

<?php
    if ($task=="insert"){

        if ($map == "nacht"){ $mapname = "Nacht Der Untoten - Rounds Survived";

            if (isset($_POST['rank'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['rounds'], $_POST['players'], $_POST['lastroundtime'], $_POST['system'], $_POST['reference'])){

                $rank = $_POST['rank'];
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $rounds = $_POST['rounds'];
                $players = $_POST['players'];
                $lastroundtime = $_POST['lastroundtime'];
                $system = $_POST['system'];
                $reference = $_POST['reference'];

                if (empty($rank) or empty($username) or empty($rounds) or empty($players) or empty($lastroundtime) or empty($system) or empty($reference)){
                    $error = "You cannot leave any boxes blank.";
                }else{
                    $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO leaderboards (rank, username, rounds, players, last_round_time, system, verified, game_id, mode_id, map_id) VALUES (:rank, :username, :rounds, :players, :last_round_time, :system, :reference, 3, 1, 8)');

                    $query->bindValue(':rank', $rank, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(':rounds', $rounds, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->bindValue(':players', $players, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->bindValue(':lastroundtime', $lastroundtime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->bindValue(':system', $system, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(':reference', $reference, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $query->execute();

                    $error = "Leaderboard injection successfull";

                }
        }
        print"<h2>You are inserting into <strong>$mapname</strong></h2><br><br>"; ?>
              <h4><strong>WARNNING:</strong> Please make sure you delete any data that is going to replace it first before inserting new one.
                    <small>For example: Dont make a new person rank 5 if you have already got someone as rank 5.</small></h4><br>

        <?php
        if (isset($error)){
            print"<h2 style=\"color:black;\">$error</h2>";
            print"<br />";
        } ?>

        <form action="lbpanelwawmap.php?task=insert&map=nacht" method="post">
            <h4>Rank</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="rank" placeholder="Enter the persons rank on the leaderboards" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>Username</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Their online name, eg: Xbox gamertag" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>Rounds</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="rounds" placeholder="How many rounds did the survive?" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>Players</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="players" placeholder="Number of players in the game" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>Last Round Time</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="lastroundtime" placeholder="How long their last round took" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>System</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="system" placeholder="What platform are they playing on?" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>
            <h4>Reference</h4><br>
            <input type="text" name="reference" placeholder="Youtube video link goes here" style="width:350px;"/><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"  style="width:100px;height:50px;"/> <br>
        </form>

<?php
}
```

Comment: You've bind lastroundtime but the correct name is :last_round_time

Answer (score 2):

You are binding `:lastroundtime` when you have specified `:last_round_time` in your prepared statement.

The error is telling you that you haven't bound all the parameters you included in your prepared statement.